# PHP File Not Copying across

Tags: php, file, upload, copy

My issue with the below code is the `if(if(empty($fields['Remuse'])))` statement everything else works fine.  I only put it in an if statement to make the warning that it was empty go away now it does not copy when there is a file - Shows in cache and db fine why?

**Issue:**

```
  $candidateuploaddir = _MYSITEDIR . '/downloads/refocus_candidates/';
        $candiatefilename = $fields['RenamedResume'];
        $candidatefile = $candidateuploaddir . $candiatefilename;

        if(empty($fields['Remuse']))
        {
                echo 'null';
        }else{
        copy($fields['Resume'],$candiatefilename);
        }
```

**Upload Function:**

```
function uploadResume()
{
    if (!isset($_FILES['UploadResume'])) return false;
    $uploaddir = _CACHEDIR.'/resumes/';
    /* create the upload folder if it does not already exist */
    CMS::RecursiveMkdir($uploaddir);
    $extension = CMS::getFileExtension(basename($_FILES['UploadResume']['name']));
    /* keep producing random filenames until we get a unique one */
    while (empty($filename) || CMS::fileExists($uploaddir.$filename)) {
        $filename = CMS::randomString(10).'.'.$extension;
    }

    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['UploadResume']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){

        return $uploadfile;
        //$uploadfile;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**On Submit Line:**

```
$fields['Resume'] = CMS::either(CMS_Plugin_plugin_jobs_apply::uploadResume(), CMS::getFormData('Resume', false)); //upload resume to temporary location
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it `if(if(empty($fields['Remuse'])))` or `if(empty($fields['Remuse']))`?

**Is it `$fields['Remuse']` or `$fields['Resume']`?**

---

```
if (empty($fields['Resume']))
{
    echo 'null';
}

else
{
    copy($fields['Resume'],$candiatefilename);
}
```

Comment: Hey,  Thanks for that but I am now getting failed to open stream: Permission denied in on the copy line any ideas why both cache and downloads are at 777

Comment: chown apache:apache <directory name>?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/` between `$uploaddir` and `$filename`.